# Copy PHAsset from Gallery to other directory in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios9, deprecated

I came through the following link which demonstrated how to copy file from Gallery to application or other directory (in right answer):

[How to copy an image file from iOS Photo Library (ALAssetsLibrary) to the local directory of an App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734070/how-to-copy-an-image-file-from-ios-photo-library-alassetslibrary-to-the-local)

But with ALAssetsLibrary class documentation Apple said its now deprecated as of iOS 9.0 instead use Photos framework.

> The Assets Library framework is deprecated as of iOS 9.0. Instead, use
>   the Photos framework instead, which in iOS 8.0 and later provides more
>   features and better performance for working with a user’s photo
>   library. For more information, see Photos Framework Reference.

How I can use Photos framework to copy assets from Gallery to other URL?

Answer (score 6):

This seems fairly easy. I added an example code for someone whom it may help:

```
    var item: PHAsset! // you update with actual PHAsset at runtime
    let docuPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.ApplicationDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true) as NSArray
    let targetImgeURL = (docuPath[0] as! String) + "/IMG_0005.JPG"
    let phManager = PHImageManager.defaultManager()
    let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
    options.synchronous = true; // do it if you want things running in background thread
    phManager.requestImageDataForAsset(item, options: options)
    {   imageData,dataUTI,orientation,info in

        if let newData:NSData = imageData
        {
            try! newData.writeToFile(targetImgeURL, atomically: true)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the **Objective C** solution.

```
  -(NSURL*)createVideoCopyFromReferenceUrl:(NSURL*)inputUrlFromVideoPicker{

        NSURL __block *videoURL;
        PHFetchResult *phAssetFetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[inputUrlFromVideoPicker ] options:nil];
        PHAsset *phAsset = [phAssetFetchResult firstObject];
        dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
        dispatch_group_enter(group);

        [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:phAsset options:nil resultHandler:^(AVAsset *asset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info) {

            if ([asset isKindOfClass:[AVURLAsset class]]) {
                NSURL *url = [(AVURLAsset *)asset URL];
                NSLog(@"Final URL %@",url);
                NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

                // optionally, write the video to the temp directory
                NSString *videoPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f.mp4",[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]]];

                videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];
                BOOL writeResult = [videoData writeToURL:videoURL atomically:true];

                if(writeResult) {
                    NSLog(@"video success");
                }
                else {
                    NSLog(@"video failure");
                }
                 dispatch_group_leave(group);
                // use URL to get file content
            }
        }];
        dispatch_group_wait(group,  DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        return videoURL;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift use below set of code

```
import Photos

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

if let referenceURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL {
    let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs([referenceURL], options: nil)
    if let phAsset = fetchResult.firstObject as? PHAsset {
        PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestAVAssetForVideo(phAsset, options: PHVideoRequestOptions(), resultHandler: { (asset, audioMix, info) -> Void in
            if let asset = asset as? AVURLAsset {
                let videoData = NSData(contentsOfURL: asset.URL)

                // optionally, write the video to the temp directory
                let videoPath = NSTemporaryDirectory() + "tmpMovie.MOV"
                let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath)
                let writeResult = videoData?.writeToURL(videoURL, atomically: true)

                if let writeResult = writeResult where writeResult {
                    print("success")
                }
                else {
                    print("failure")
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

}
```